# Teradata, volatile table and nocount?

Tags: teradata

So I'm having some issues with a ETL-job where I'm trying to query out a statement including the creation of a volatile table (VT) with the adjoining insert.

Though I'm not sure I think I'm having an issue equivalent to MS-SQL temp table insert if you don't have the "SET NOCOUNT ON" -> I.e. the row count from the insert into the VT is returned to my to my cursor instead of the query using the VT.

I can't use a CTE (don't think I can) because I am inserting a pivoted result into the VT as I need to be able to reference the columns in the main select.

I can't create a view because this is a managed system for a banking core solution; with other words I have no right other than read from which I use to synthesize data from views and extract them.
For the same reason I can't create a stored procedure.

I've googled my way half around the world in 2,5 languages, but I'm not able to find any Teradata equivalent of "SET NOCOUNT ON".

I'm triggering the load from Azure Data Factory and I have a On Prem self hosted integration runtime to ensure connectivity to the TeradataDB.

Needless to say Teradata is not my strong suit and I'm hoping for some help from you guys :)

In advance! Many thanks!

Edit:

So here is the structure of the query:

```
Create volatile table StackOverflowTable
(
    Key1(40),
    Pivot1 float,
    Pivot2 float,
    Pivot3 float
)primary index (Key1) ON COMMIT PRESERVE ROWS;

;


insert into StackOverflowTable
select *
from
(
    select atv.row1 Key1
    , atv.row2
    atv.row3
    , row_number() over(partition by atv.row1 order by atv.row2 desc) RowNum
    from aTeradataView  atv
)s1
Pivot
(
    sum(s1.row2) amt1,
    sum(s1.row3) amt2
    for RowNum in(1,2,3,4)
)p

;


with cte as
(
    select av.row_av_1
    , av.row_av_2
    , av.row_av_3
    , av.row_av_4
    , av.ReportDate
    from anotherView av
)



select cte.row_av_1
, cte.row_av_2
, cte.row_av_3
, cte.row_av_4
, sf.Pivot1 
, sf.Pivot2
, sf.Pivot3
, cte.ReportDate StartLoadDate
, '9999-12-31' EndLoadDate
from cte
inner join StackOverflowTable sf on sf = cte.row_av_1

;

DROP TABLE StackOverflowTable 
;
```

Comment: I don't understand your problem. Can you add more details on your processing steps? Why can't you use a CTE to *reference the columns in the main select* (Btw, you can use an alias in any query clause without CTE/Derived Table). You might be able to create views in your own user (it's usually not restricted) for your personal use (can't grant rights on it to other users for security reasons)

Comment: @dnoeth thanks for getting back to me so soon! So the reason I'm not going with a view is because a stored procedure would be needed -> it's parameterized. So the problem I'm having with the CTE is that, becuase the base data is the result of a pivoted table, I can't "Select cte.*pivot1*, cte.*pivot2* from cte". When I create a volatile table I can do just that. I'll add some more info about the query in the body above^^

Comment: Still confusing :-) You can access the pivoted columns, but you need to know the names. They get automatically assigned like `1_amt1` and if starting with a digit you must double quote them `"1_amt1"`. Or you assign aliases like `for RowNum in(1 as c1,2 as c2,3 as c3 ,4 as c4)`, which result in `c1_amt1`, etc. Regarding parameterizing you might be able to do it in a *macro*, which is similar to a SP, but without all features like loop/if besides parameters (similar to views you should be able to create them within your own user).

Comment: I still don't understand your NO COUNT problem. Both the Insert/Select and the Select will return their activity count.

Comment: God damn Dnoeth! for RowNum in(1 as c1,2 as c2,3 as c3 ,4 as c4), which result in c1_amt1 solved my problem and I'm able to reference the columns from SQL. I frequently Pivot so I'll bring that over to my reqular MS SQL as well. So many thanks.

Comment: When it comes to the NO COUNT problem: I can only speak for MS SQL, but say you have a stored procedure with temp tables that you insert into. If you don't set NOCOUNT on the row count from the first insert is returned from the sproc and you don't get the result from that o' so savory select at the bottom that you really want yielded. Again. You made my day Dnoeth -> I'd buy you a beer if I had you at my local bar :)